# How to cite a spoken quote?

Tags: citations, citation-style, quotation

I have a quote spoken by a person in an interview, how do I cite it?

> Chinua Achebe, the prominent Nigerian novelist and essayist who died
> on Thursday, said in a 1994 interview with the Paris Review, "There is
> that great proverb — that until the lions have their own historians,
> the history of the hunt will always glorify the hunter."

i would like to know how to cite a quote in:

- a chat
- a speech
- and a citation of spoken word

I've looked in the documentation for Chicago manual style for how to do this and searched on google but could not find how.

Comment: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/chicago_manual_17th_edition/cmos_formatting_and_style_guide/interviews_personal_communication.html